# External HDD only shows on clean startup of Windows

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, lenovo-laptop, usb-3

my Lenovo laptop with Windows 10 does this weird thing:

If I connect my external USB 3 hard drive to my USB 3 port and the computer is not completly turned off, the disc won't show up in Windows. After a clean boot (or a restart) the external drive shows up and works smoothly only until the next Sleep/Hibernation mode.
What I tried so far:

1. `sfc /scannow`
2. use the laptop only with the power cord plugged in
3. change the 'USB selective suspend' setting to Never
4. use the Y cable for more power to the USB
5. reinstall the USB drivers
6. update BIOS

...and many others, but nothing helped yet.

Do you have any clue, what else can be wrong?

Comment: Turn off, remove the USB drive, start up and test. Does that work?  if so (a) somewhat known issue and (b) update BIOS and test that

Comment: In case it is a 2.5" hard drive without own power supply make sure to use only USB 3.0 ports (those with blue color). USB 2.0 port don't provide enough power and can be damaged. And Y-cables are bad anyway (forbidden by USB spec) - better to use an active powered USB-hub in between of PC and HDD instead.

Comment: In Services, do you find one called UASPStor? If so, it should be set to Demand start and running when your USB drive is plugged in.

Comment: What is the model of the Lenovo laptop? I don't remember any laptop from Lenovo which had all __3.0 USB__ ports. What if you need an external mouse, which one could you use?

Comment: My laptop is Thinkpad X260.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a partial solution using the Y cable, but it is not what I've expected:

1. connect drive to the cable
2. connect the "power only" cable to the laptop
3. wait at least 30 seconds (otherwise it will fail with "USB device not recognised" error)
4. connect the "power & data" cable to the laptop

This is what currently works the best for me, but I know that it is not a proper bugfix.